# WPF ScrollViewer for ListBox -> Performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer, ui-virtualization

I'm trying to create `grid` with `listbox` with `Scrollbar`.
It's done somehow like that:

```
<Grid>
<ListBox Name="xxx" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
....
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that if I use scrollbar, then the size of bar-button jumps back and forward within scrolling. If I remove `ScrollViewer` from properties and instead put ListBox in `ScrollViewer` tag, then everything is working perfect, except of terrible performance of rerendering UI (resize, move window, resource consuming). According to google it does "disable virtualization". This sounds crazy that there's no simple solution to get properly working scrollbar and usable UI without issues.

Is there compromise for both of these things? Virtualization + properly working `scrollviewer` with fixed size of `scrollbar` button.

Comment: This is probably because the items in your ListView are not of the same size. What are you trying to display with this ListView?

Comment: Yes, they're not the same size. Just displaying items with several paragraphs of text each.

Comment: You could try to make each item only one line of text (just for testing reasons).